# Ada: Entry meaning

Tags: ada

I am an absolute beginner with Ada, and there's one thing I cannot find a concrete definition for - that's the statement `entry`.

I understand an entry with a barrier - if the barrier is true, the statement can execute and if false, the task is queued until it's evaluated to be true.

For example:

```
entry Get(Item : out Data_Item) when Number_In_Buffer /= 0 is
begin
...
end Get;
```

But what does it mean for the statement `entry` to appear **without** a following `when` statement?

Answer (score 4):

[ARM9.4](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-4.html) describes protected objects, which is where entry bodies (as in your code) occur.

It’s not clear from your question, but I think you’re describing a protected specification, with an entry declaration.

[Declaration](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-4.html#p27):

```
protected type Resource is
   entry Seize;
   procedure Release;
private
   Busy : Boolean := False;
end Resource;
```

[Corresponding body](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-4.html#p28):

```
protected body Resource is
   entry Seize when not Busy is
   begin
      Busy := True;
   end Seize;

   procedure Release is
   begin
      Busy := False;
   end Release;
end Resource;
```

It is not the caller’s business how the entry is guarded, just that it is. One thing that’s caught me out a couple of times is that an entry body *must* have a guard; there are some circumstances (requeueing - search [the Ada 95 Rationale II.9](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#9)  for `protected Event`) where `when True` is OK.

Comment: @User9123 To add to Simon's explanation, you appear to be unclear about the differences between a the specification for a protected object and the body of the protected object. The guard is only in the body, not in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

An ENTRY is also a connection point for TASK communication.  In the TASK definition, it is ENTRY.  In the TASK BODY, it is an ACCEPT statement.  So every ENTRY in a TASK definition has a corresponding ACCEPT in the TASK body.

Comment: Not strictly true, though probably indicates a mistake. GNAT will warn you about this (you may have to give the right options, `-gnatwa`, I think). It is true that each `accept` in the body has to have a corresponding `entry` in the spec.